# How to remove the schedule from a journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

[This](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_copy_a_journey.htm&type=5) Salesforce help documentation, about copying journeys, states: "If the journey includes an automated schedule, create a draft, remove the schedule, and save the journey before you make a copy."

However, I have no idea how to do that. I can only view the schedule, but I don't see any means of removing it. I am an administrator, so I should have sufficient permissions.

Comment: Are you doing this in a draft or in an active journey?

Comment: In a Draft journey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to remove/delete the Entry Source (data extension) in order to remove the schedule.  But copying the Journey when you get the "The schedule for this entry source exists in the past. If you create a copy of this journey, you must create a new entry source definition." error will do the same thing.

If you have the location of your Entry Event data extension you can go about it in two ways.

(1) Copy the journey without removing the data extension, ignore the warning message,it will allow you to make the copy.  The copy will not have an entry event when created.
(2) Delete the Entry event (if you hover over the Entry Event circle you'll see a small trash icon to delete).  Then you can copy the Journey without receiving the message but the end result will be the same as step 1.  WARNING: Only delete the entry event if the Journey you are using has been archived and not used as future drafts will not be reliable when deleting a DE and adding it back.

When making a copy make sure all your activities are validated when you reconnect the entry event and schedule.

[image]

Comment: Well, in my case MC behaves differently. First, I don't get the error that you mentioned, that is just text from the help documentation. Second, copying a journey with the DE also copies the Event entry. I guess it will work, because I only get a warning when viewing the DE: "You have selected a data source that is already used for one or more other journeys. Using the same data extension for multiple journeys will impact the performance of each journey using this source because ..." So I guess it will work, as long as the two journeys work at different times.

Comment: But I'll approve your answer, because removing the schedule seems to require that the Entry Source has been removed first.

Comment: I'm glad you are finding the path, I updated the post to include the error message seen in our instance.  Good luck, JB is such an amazing tool!

Comment: What is your use case where multiple journeys need access to the same data extension that sounds like is updated via an automation?

Comment: My real problem is that I want to change the Contact Entry journey setting from "Re-entry only after exiting" into "No re-entry", but that is not possible for versions of the same journey. You must make a copy to be able to change it.

Comment: I hear you on that limitation and sounds good.  Remember to check all of the journey activities on the copy as connecting even the same DE can throw off the data populating down the journey canvas.